# How to get the "get_option" value in json in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Angular 2 in a plugin which should communicate with WordPress. I'd use the Options API, how could I get the value of "get_option" in json?

Comment: Currently, `options` is not available in core WP API v2, but you can [extend](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/) it for your purpose.

Comment: The http://v2.wp-api.org is a plugin. Or is the rest API already included in WP core?

Comment: No, REST API isn't already included in core, the proposal is v4.7. So the plugin is a temporary solution now. You can find out more info on [Make WordPress](https://make.wordpress.org/core/?s=REST+API).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll check it.